# How to interpolate some parts of numpy array in which they are in the maximum k values with nearest neighbor element value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I meet a problem. Now I have a numpy array 'A'. In A, there some parts with the maximum k values， I want to interpolate these parts with nearest neighbor items for numpy array. How to do this?

Example:

```
A = np.array([[1, 0, 2, 3, 3],
              [0, 1, 4, 5, 3],
              [3, 2, 1, 5, 2],
              [0, 1, -1, 1, 3],
              [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]])
```

I want to interpolate the element whose value >= 4 with nearest neighbor element value.

Anyone can give some advises?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a small example here? Currently it's a bit hard to understand what you actually want.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my question.

Comment: Could you add the expected output of the above as well? As I understand it, values >=4 should be removed and the interpolated value of the neighbors should be used (1-dim or 2-dim)? The second row 4,5 should be 1.66/2.33?